# How does finding the error work in the back propogation of a CNN when 4D tensors are used?

Tags: machine-learning, conv-neural-network, c++

I am currently creating a CNN from scratch in C++ only using vectors, and Matrix classes I have created. Mainly doing this as an exercise so that I can make sure I fully understand the process. I am currently able to do the forward pass, along with the backwards pass as it pertains to `dw` and `db`. `dw` being the gradient of the weight tensor, and `db` being the gradient of the bias tensor. However, I am having an issue finding `dx` which is the error as it pertains to the next layer. I will be calling it `dx` for this post. Currently when I need to find dx when only dealing with 2 dimensional matricies, it works perfectly.

The code for finding `dx` would be like this (for 2D matricies):

```
Matrix<float> rotated = kernel.rotate_180();
Matrix<float> dx = dz.convolute_full(rotated);
```

and `dw` would be (for 2D matricies):
`Matrix<float> dw = a_prev.convolute(dz);`

Which works.

When working with four dimensional tensors, this is my code for finding dw:

```
//(a_prev and dz both have a layer of 1)
std::vector<Matrix> a_prevs = a_prev.at(0);
std::vector<Matrix> dzs = dz.at(0);
std::vector<std::vector<Matrix>> dw;
for(uint32_t i = 0; i < dzs.size(); i++){
   std::vector<Matrix> part;
   for(uint32_t j = 0; j < a_prevs.size(); j++){
      part.push_back(a_prevs.at(j).convolute(dzs.at(i)));
   }
   dw.push_back(part);
}
```

And this entirely works for getting `dw` when using multi-dimensional tensors. However, when getting `dx` it doesn't work as smoothly. This is what I would think the code for finding dx would be:

```
//in this case, dz has the dimensions (1,4,6,6) and the kernel corresponding to this layer with dimensions (4,4,3,3)
//after the kernel is rotated, the rotated should have the same dimensions as the kernel which are (4,4,3,3)

std::vector<Matrix> dzs = dz.at(0);
std::vector<std::vector<Matrix>> rotated = rotate_180(kernel);
std::vector<std::vector<Matrix>> combos;
for(uint32_t i = 0; i < dzs.size(); i++){
   std::vector<Matrix> combo;
   for(uint32_t j = 0; j < rotated.at(i).size(); j++){
      combo.push_back(dzs.at(i).convolute_full(rotated.at(i).at(j)));
   }
   combos.push_back(combo);
}
std::vector<std::vector<Matrix>> dx = {combos.at(0)};
for(uint32_t i = 1; i < combos.size(); i++){
   dx = add(dx, combos.at(i));
}
```

However, when I use this as dx, the errors only become larger. I have already confirmed that `dw` works for four dimensional tensors. I have gotten the following formulas for when dw and dx are 4 dimensional tensors from [this website](https://numbersmithy.com/back-propagation-in-a-convolution-layer-with-numpy-implementation/#comment-6629).

For the finding of dw I used this formula:
`∂/∂(,)=(−1)⊗(,),=1,2,⋯,()`

For the finding of dx I used this formula:
`(−1)=∑=1()[(,)⊗180((,))`

On the website linked above, the formula includes a hadamard product of what was then `dz` sent through the derivative of the activation function. I did not include this in my code. I am trying to implement the back propgation of dx without the ativation function, purely for self learning purposes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically, the code posted above is not incorrect, except for the fact it is not memory efficient. However, at the end a function similar to `numpy.clip` needs to be implemented to `dx`. So the code would be:

```
std::vector<Matrix> dzs = dz.at(0);
std::vector<std::vector<Matrix>> rotated = rotate_180(kernel);
std::vector<std::vector<Matrix>> combos;
for(uint32_t i = 0; i < dzs.size(); i++){
   std::vector<Matrix> combo;
   for(uint32_t j = 0; j < rotated.at(i).size(); j++){
      combo.push_back(dzs.at(i).convolute_full(rotated.at(i).at(j)));
   }
   combos.push_back(combo);
}
std::vector<std::vector<Matrix>> dx = {combos.at(0)};
for(uint32_t i = 1; i < combos.size(); i++){
   dx = add(dx, combos.at(i));
}

dx = clip(dx, CLIP_MAX, CLIP_MIN);
```

Notice the only difference is the last line. For those that don't know, the function of `numpy.clip` is to make all values above `CLIP_MAX` equal to `CLIP_MAX` and all values below `CLIP_MIN` equal to `CLIP_MIN`.